# same textfile from data source to HDFS using flafka

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, flume-ng

I'm developping the architeture below:

1)flume agent_a tailing textfiles in a data source directory and moving them in kafka topic.

2)flume agent_b moving the textfile from the kafka topic to hdfs.

I 'm a little confused about this issue:

**How can I be sure that the agent_b will take the data from the kafka topic in order to ingest in HDFS exactly the same textfile (same row, in the same sequence) that the agent_a took from the data source directory?.**

Tnks

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include examples and more information

Answer (score 0):

Flume should be maintaining the source offset for the input file and batching them into a Kafka Producer in that order.

If you have multiple partitions in the Kafka topic, though, you can't make any ordering guarantees.

Comment: Hello, tnks for the answer :)In my agent_a I'm using Taildir_source saving the path of the file that I'm tailing in the Header. I would like to use the path as the key for the partition when I save the event in kafka topic. I must specify this property in the kafka sink configuration of the agent_a but I can't find the property to declare. The flume userGuide  reports that _ Any producer property supported by Kafka can be used_ I can't find the property to use to assign the key to the partition. Can someone give me a hand?